# How do i create a text input with markdown highlighting in react?

Tags: reactjs, markdown

I need to build an input where you could use markdown syntax such as *italic*, **bold**, `inline code` and codeblock and preview markdown as you write it, i also need syntax highlighting for the codeblocks.

Is there an easy way to build something like this from scratch?

This is more or less the result i'd like (src: Discord)

[image: Discord text input]

I have tried some libraries such as [@uiw/react-md-editor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@uiw/react-md-editor) but they all come with some limitations: in some you cannot customize the preview styles at all, some do not support syntax highlighting, some are too complex for such a simple thing.

Additional info: i am using nextjs